# (Total) Derivative of a Function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I wonder wether my function $f:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ given by
$$ f(x,y) = y^{-1}\exp(-0.5x^2y^{-2})$$
has a total derivative. This function is clearly partial differentiable (w.r.t. $x$ and $y$) and these derivatives are continuous so using a theorem which states that existing continuous partial derivatives implies (total) differentiable I suppose that $f$ is indeed (total) differentiable. Is it then correct that the (total) derivative $Df$ is given by
$$Df = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{x}{y^2} \\ \frac{x^2 - y^2}{y^3}\end{pmatrix}f(x,y).$$
(Results are from wolfram alpha). In other words, my question is wether $Df$ is given by the matrix of partial derivatives?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) the total derivative is not a vector. Since you explicitly wrote "matrix": Do you confuse it with the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of functions $f:ℝ^n→ℝ^m$ or the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient)?

Comment: @P.Siehr some books refer total derivative as the linear transformation represented by the Jacobian.

Comment: What you've written is a gradient. May be you've meant the total differential $df=\partial_{x}fdx+\partial_{y}fdy$?

Comment: @LiChunMin Can you name me one? I am always looking forward to read about definitions / concepts, which are different to what I am used to.

Comment: @P.Siehr you may have a look at the analysis book written by Apostol. I think chapter 12 unified the concepts of direction derivative, gradient and Jacobian well. Apostol is also my first read on rigorous multivariable calculus. I guess the OP might also want to have a look :)

Comment: As @LiChunMin already said in his comments, there seems to be a little confusion regarding the termes I have used. My function maps $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ with $n=2$ and $m=1$, so the linear map is a $2\times 1$ "matrix" (or call it vector).

See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_linear_map
I think I should have omitted the word "total" and just called it differentiable but I wanted to stick with the definition given on wikipedia to link it if necessary

Comment: Your $f$ does not have partial derivatives everywhere. Tell us where the function is defined.

Comment: True, we need the restriction that $y\neq0$. I will add that, thanks

Comment: Let $g(t) = f(x(t),y(t)) = y(t)^{-1}\exp(-0.5x(t)^2y(t)^{-2})$ then $g'(t) = x'(t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}{\scriptstyle(x(t),y(t))}+y'(t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}{\scriptstyle(x(t),y(t))}$. That's all.